# Android - Get result from change default SMS app dialog

Tags: java, android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on restoring SMS on KITKAT. Referring to this [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) I have added the things which are required to set my app as default app for SMS. After adding all required things in manifest file I have write the following code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{
    mDefaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(mContext);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, mContext.getPackageName());
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image]

The above code shows this dialog but I am unable to get the result from this activity/dialog either user clicked on Yes or No because I want to add listener or get any code which should represent that the user clicked on these buttons.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible but why you are doing this ? Afaik SMS and Hangout message use a content provider. It depends on user where he wants to have messages.

Comment: @Williams I am doing this because in Android Kitkat and above the only default SMS app can write messages. I will set my app as default app before restoring messages and set again previous app as default after restore completed.

Comment: Are you doing this from an Activity?

Comment: @MikeM. I am doing it in simple class with Activity Context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is to fire the Intent with `startActivityForResult()`, and then check the `resultCode` in the `onActivityResult()` method. Please note that I've changed the code in the example to run in an Activity's Context.

```
private static final int DEF_SMS_REQ = 0;
private String mDefaultSmsApp;

...

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        mDefaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this);

        if (!getPackageName().equals(mDefaultSmsApp))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
            startActivityForResult(intent, DEF_SMS_REQ);
        }
    }       

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case DEF_SMS_REQ:           
            boolean isDefault = resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK;
            ...
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned in a comment below, apparently checking the result code is not 100% reliable. A safer check is to simply compare your app's package name to the current default in `onActivityResult()`. There's no need to check the result code at all, like the answer linked in the comment shows.

```
String currentDefault = Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this);
boolean isDefault = getPackageName().equals(currentDefault);
```

Comment: Above code work perfectly on Lollipop. But, not working on Kitkat. In onActivityResult it return 0 for resultCode when select "yes". Please help me.

Comment: My problem is solved, if anybody has same problem then see this question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873599/startactivityforresult-always-return-0-when-restore-sms/29876919?noredirect=1#comment47905721_29876919

Answer (score 0):

The way you can react on "yes" button click:

```
private String mDefSmsPackage;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle state) {
    //...
    mDefSmsPackage = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity())
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String newDefSmsPkg = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity());
    if (!TextUtils.equals(mDefSmsPackage, newDefSmsPkg)) {
        mDefSmsPackage = newDefSmsPkg;

        //ON DEF SMS APP CAHNGE...

    }
}
```