# startActivityForResult always return 0 when restore sms

Tags: android, android-intent

This code working properly on lollypop version, But, when i use it on Kitkat, it always returns 0 when i choose "Yes/No" option from dialog.

```
btnSMSRestore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
                    defaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(SMSActivity.this);
                    if (!getPackageName().equals(defaultSmsApp))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                        intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
                        //startActivity(intent);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, DEF_SMS_REQ);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    new RestoreSMS().execute();
                }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case DEF_SMS_REQ:           
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                new RestoreSMS().execute();
            }
    }
}
```

Activity.RESULT_OK value is -1 and resultCode in onActivityResult is always 0 when use with kitkat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)):

> **onActivityResult** Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it
>   returned, and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be
>   RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't
>   return any result, or crashed during its operation.

`RESULT_CANCELED` value is 0, probably on KitKat is not set a result value and the default one is returned.

As workaround on KitKat, you can try to check if your app is the default one when onActivityResult is fired. Try this code:

```
btnSMSRestore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (!isDefaultSmsApp(SMSActivity.this)) {
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
                startActivityForResult(intent, DEF_SMS_REQ);
            }
        } else {
            new RestoreSMS().execute();
        }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case DEF_SMS_REQ:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isDefaultSmsApp(this) ||
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                new RestoreSMS().execute();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static boolean isDefaultSmsApp(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName().equals(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context));
}
```

Comment: My app is change to default sms app but, result code not match toActivity.RESULT_OK so, my action is not perform in application

Comment: Please look at the updated answer. I have tested and the code works both on KitKat and Lollipop. Let me know

Comment: Thanks for reply i will test it and revert you back :)

Comment: @sanat shukla Have you tested the solution? If the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks

Comment: Shall we get user Clicked `Yes` or `No`

Comment: @SANAT Shall we get user Clicked Yes or No ?