# My camera application not working on kitkat but working on other phones

Tags: android

As soon as I capture the image in my kitkat device, the code is directly going to elseif condition where it shows `User cancelled image capture` while it works fine on another api devices.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

// key to store image path in savedInstance state
public static final String KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH = "image_path";

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

// Bitmap sampling size
public static final int BITMAP_SAMPLE_SIZE = 8;

// Gallery directory name to store the images or videos
public static final String GALLERY_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

// Image and Video file extensions
public static final String IMAGE_EXTENSION = "jpg";
public static final String VIDEO_EXTENSION = "mp4";

private static String imageStoragePath;

private TextView txtDescription;
private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView videoPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Checking availability of the camera
    if (!CameraUtils.isDeviceSupportCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device doesn't have camera
        finish();
    }

    txtDescription = findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
    imgPreview = findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    videoPreview = findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
    btnCapturePicture = findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    btnRecordVideo = findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

    /**
     * Capture image on button click
     */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CameraUtils.checkPermissions(getApplicationContext())) {
                captureImage();
            } else {
                requestCameraPermission(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Record video on button click
     */
    btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CameraUtils.checkPermissions(getApplicationContext())) {
                captureVideo();
            } else {
                requestCameraPermission(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            }
        }
    });

    // restoring storage image path from saved instance state
    // otherwise the path will be null on device rotation
    restoreFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Restoring store image path from saved instance state
 */
private void restoreFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH)) {
            imageStoragePath = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageStoragePath)) {
                if (imageStoragePath.substring(imageStoragePath.lastIndexOf(".")).equals("." + IMAGE_EXTENSION)) {
                    previewCapturedImage();
                } else if (imageStoragePath.substring(imageStoragePath.lastIndexOf(".")).equals("." + VIDEO_EXTENSION)) {
                    previewVideo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Requesting permissions using Dexter library
 */
private void requestCameraPermission(final int type) {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {

                        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                            // capture picture
                            captureImage();
                        } else {
                            captureVideo();
                        }

                    } else if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        showPermissionsAlert();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}


/**
 * Capturing Camera Image will launch camera app requested image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File file = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (file != null) {
        imageStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    Uri fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Saving stored image path to saved instance state
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putString(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH, imageStoragePath);
}

/**
 * Restoring image path from saved instance state
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    imageStoragePath = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to record video
 */
private void captureVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    File file = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    if (file != null) {
        imageStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    Uri fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 */
**@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Refreshing the gallery
            CameraUtils.refreshGallery(getApplicationContext(), imageStoragePath);
            // successfully captured the image
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getExtras().get("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Refreshing the gallery
            CameraUtils.refreshGallery(getApplicationContext(), imageStoragePath);
            // video successfully recorded
            // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                    data.getExtras().get("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // preview the recorded video
            previewVideo();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}**

/**
 * Display image from gallery
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // hide video preview
        txtDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Bitmap bitmap = CameraUtils.optimizeBitmap(BITMAP_SAMPLE_SIZE, imageStoragePath);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Displaying video in VideoView
 */
private void previewVideo() {
    try {
        // hide image preview
        txtDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVideoPath(imageStoragePath);
        // start playing
        videoPreview.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Alert dialog to navigate to app settings
 * to enable necessary permissions
 */
private void showPermissionsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Permissions required!")
            .setMessage("Camera needs few permissions to work properly. Grant them in settings.")
            .setPositiveButton("GOTO SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    CameraUtils.openSettings(MainActivity.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Check your result code parameter in onActivityResult.

Comment: It always goes to RESULT_CANCELED (0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> onActivityResult Called when an activity you launched exits, giving
>   you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it returned,
>   and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be
>   RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't
>   return any result, or crashed during its operation. RESULT_CANCELED
>   value is 0, probably on KitKat is not set a result value and the
>   default one is returned.

As workaround on KitKat, you can try to check if your app is the default one when onActivityResult is fired.

Android Documentation: [Click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

For code, Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876919/6672577

**startActivityForResult**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**OnActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getExtras().get("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // display it in image view
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            previewCapturedImage(photo); // pass bitmap to the method so you can preview it.
        }
```

**previewCapturedImage**

```
private void previewCapturedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        // hide video preview
        txtDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to comment these lines ....File file = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (file != null) {
        imageStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    Uri fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

Comment: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Hello Camera/IMG_20180718_113200.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Thanks @Opriday. It worked. But preview is not there as I want to show it.

Comment: Modify your code like my answer. you will achieve your result.

Comment: Let me know If you have issue and If it work then vote up!

Comment: Sorry man, my reputation is less than **15** so I can't upvote you

Comment: Sorry man I didn't get the preview yet. If I do the same changes for the preview as you told, so in the restoreFromBundle method it also needs the previewCapturedImage method and also the image is not in the Hello Camera Directory folder.

Comment: Could you edit your question again and show your modified code maybe you have made any mistake because I checked my code and worked for me

Comment: Should I explain in **an answer for the same question**

Comment: It would be better If you show your code because I will go through your code and find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

@Opriday
Let me clear all my doubts: First of all I want to create an app for each devices (**min api 19**) and

Second I can't change the `previewCapturedImage()` to `previewCapturedImage(Bitmap bitmap)` as I can't pass `photo` as parameter because I have to call `previewCapturedImage()` in `restoreFromBundle`.

```
package info.androidhive.androidcamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

// key to store image path in savedInstance state
public static final String KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH = "image_path";

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

// Bitmap sampling size
public static final int BITMAP_SAMPLE_SIZE = 8;

// Gallery directory name to store the images or videos
public static final String GALLERY_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

// Image and Video file extensions
public static final String IMAGE_EXTENSION = "jpg";
public static final String VIDEO_EXTENSION = "mp4";

private static String imageStoragePath;

private TextView txtDescription;
private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView videoPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Checking availability of the camera
    if (!CameraUtils.isDeviceSupportCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device doesn't have camera
        finish();
    }

    txtDescription = findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
    imgPreview = findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    videoPreview = findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
    btnCapturePicture = findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    btnRecordVideo = findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

    /**
     * Capture image on button click
     */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CameraUtils.checkPermissions(getApplicationContext()) ||
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                captureImage();
            } else {
                requestCameraPermission(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Record video on button click
     */
    btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CameraUtils.checkPermissions(getApplicationContext())) {
                captureVideo();
            } else {
                requestCameraPermission(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            }
        }
    });

    // restoring storage image path from saved instance state
    // otherwise the path will be null on device rotation
    restoreFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Restoring store image path from saved instance state
 */
private void restoreFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH)) {
            imageStoragePath = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageStoragePath)) {
                if (imageStoragePath.substring(imageStoragePath.lastIndexOf(".")).equals("." + IMAGE_EXTENSION)) {
                    previewCapturedImage(photo);
                } else if (imageStoragePath.substring(imageStoragePath.lastIndexOf(".")).equals("." + VIDEO_EXTENSION)) {
                    previewVideo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Requesting permissions using Dexter library
 */
private void requestCameraPermission(final int type) {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {

                        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                            // capture picture
                            captureImage();
                        } else {
                            captureVideo();
                        }

                    } else if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        showPermissionsAlert();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}


/**
 * Capturing Camera Image will launch camera app requested image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    /*File file = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (file != null) {
        imageStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    Uri fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);*/

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Saving stored image path to saved instance state
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putString(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH, imageStoragePath);
}

/**
 * Restoring image path from saved instance state
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    imageStoragePath = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_IMAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to record video
 */
private void captureVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    File file = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    if (file != null) {
        imageStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    Uri fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(getApplicationContext(), file);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {

        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ||
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {*/
            // if the result is capturing Image
            // Refreshing the gallery
            CameraUtils.refreshGallery(getApplicationContext(), imageStoragePath);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            previewCapturedImage(photo);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Refreshing the gallery
            CameraUtils.refreshGallery(getApplicationContext(), imageStoragePath);

            // video successfully recorded
            // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                    data.getExtras().get("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // preview the recorded video
            previewVideo();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static boolean isDefaultSmsApp(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName().equals(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context));
}

/**
 * Display image from gallery
 */
private void previewCapturedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        // hide video preview
        txtDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Bitmap bitmap = CameraUtils.optimizeBitmap(BITMAP_SAMPLE_SIZE, imageStoragePath);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Displaying video in VideoView
 */
private void previewVideo() {
    try {
        // hide image preview
        txtDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVideoPath(imageStoragePath);
        // start playing
        videoPreview.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Alert dialog to navigate to app settings
 * to enable necessary permissions
 */
private void showPermissionsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Permissions required!")
            .setMessage("Camera needs few permissions to work properly. Grant them in settings.")
            .setPositiveButton("GOTO SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    CameraUtils.openSettings(MainActivity.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).show();
}
```

}

And this is **CameraUtils.java** activity in which I want to show the preview of captured image or may be galleryView if possible.

```
package info.androidhive.androidcamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CameraUtils {

/**
 * Refreshes gallery on adding new image/video. Gallery won't be refreshed
 * on older devices until device is rebooted
 */

public static void refreshGallery(Context context, String filePath) {
    // ScanFile so it will be appeared on Gallery
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[]{filePath}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                }
            });
}

public static boolean checkPermissions(Context context) {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

/**
 * Downsizing the bitmap to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions
 */
public static Bitmap optimizeBitmap(int sampleSize, String filePath) {
    // bitmap factory
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
    // images
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}

/**
 * Checks whether device has camera or not. This method not necessary if
 * android:required="true" is used in manifest file
 */
public static boolean isDeviceSupportCamera(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Open device app settings to allow user to enable permissions
 */
public static void openSettings(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(Context context, File file) {
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
}

/**
 * Creates and returns the image or video file before opening the camera
 */
public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            MainActivity.GALLERY_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.GALLERY_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + MainActivity.GALLERY_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Preparing media file naming convention
    // adds timestamp
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MainActivity.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + "." + MainActivity.IMAGE_EXTENSION);
    } else if (type == MainActivity.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + "." + MainActivity.VIDEO_EXTENSION);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```