# how to set onclick in Android in built in alertdialog

Tags: android, disabled-control

I am developing an message app . My app can be default or not . I can make my app default by the following app .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,myPackageName);
startActivity(intent);
```

When this code is executed the following alert dialogue is present in my app .The alert dialogue is built-in . I do not write code for it . For the above code , the alert dialogue is present .
[image]

When I click on Yes button , I need to call enable_view() function . When I click NO button , I need to call disable_view() function . How can I do that ?

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27010644/2365507

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement onActivityResult method to get result from sms default intent .. like this example

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqcode, int rescode, Intent arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(reqcode, rescode, arg2);
    switch (reqcode) {
        case IS_APP_DEFAULT_ID:
            if (rescode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 //call enable view here
            } else {
                  //call disabel view here
            }
    }

}
```

And you have to use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understading you need an alertbox with yes and no options with custom actions in it.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Use super duper message app instead of default messaging app");

      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
          //positive button action  goes here
         }
      });

      alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           //negative button action goes here
         }
      });

      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
   }
```

Cheers!